# project migrating to new version of java (Java 1.8)

Tags: java

Currently my project uses java 1.7 and we have requirement to upgrade it to 1.8.
what are the key points i have to consider before estimating the hours?

Comment: Since java is backward compatible, you will be able to switch versions easily.

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha you have obviously never migrated a bigger project to a new java version.

Comment: Nobody can answer this question without that amount of details. Are you also talking about migrating your production environment with java8 runtimes? Do you have bytecode manipulation (for instance javassist from powermock etc, that was a real pain going from j6 to j7)? How many projects are we talking about? Do you have a buildserver that need to be j8 as well? To you have code scanners such as sonar?

Comment: The most important thing you have to consider is changing from util.Date to java.time

Comment: its is not production env but our project compiler/jdk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just try to update already and see what is breaking before coming up with an estimate.

**There may be no work at all.**

Answer (score 0):

1. Dependencies
2. Build setup
3. Custom JVM parameters

It might work just after an update, it might take a month. Depending on your project.